# what is the order of the dictionary in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a question about the order of the dictionary in python. I am in python 2.7

```
array ={"dad":"nse","cat":"error","bob":"das","nurse":"hello"}

for key in array:
    print key
```

why result shows

```
dad
bob
nurse
cat
```

NOT

```
dad 
cat
bob
nurse
```

Comment: there is no order in dicts

Comment: Please look into documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is the order in Python dictionaries and sets arbitrary?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15479928/why-is-the-order-in-python-dictionaries-and-sets-arbitrary)

Answer (score 1):

In the standard Python implementation, CPython, dictionaries have no guaranteed order, [per the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.items).

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html), there is no ordering to the elements in a dictionary. Python can return the entries to you in whatever order it chooses. If you want a dictionary with order, you can use an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict). However, since it must maintain order, this collection has worse performance than a normal Dict.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I agree, dictionary is an independent data structure, which means it always live its life :) , but check out this example:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
days = {"Monday": 1, "Tuesday": 2, "Wednesday": 3, "Thursday": 4, "Friday": 5}
print days
sorted_days = OrderedDict(sorted(days.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
print sorted_days
print list(days)[0]
print list(sorted_days)[0]
```

With output:

```
{'Friday': 5, 'Tuesday': 2, 'Thursday': 4, 'Wednesday': 3, 'Monday': 1}
OrderedDict([('Monday', 1), ('Tuesday', 2), ('Wednesday', 3), ('Thursday', 4), ('Friday', 5)])
Friday
Monday
```

In lambda expression `t[1]` indicates: according to what, the dictionary will be sorted. So I think it might solve the problem.

But.. couldn't find a strict answer why dictionary has such order when printed. I suppose it's a matter of memory, where the dictionary arranges itself.